# Misaligned labels in Seaborn ridge plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I noticed that if I change this line `g.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.25)` in Seaborn ridge plot example [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html), the labels don't align well. For example if I change the line to `g.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.9)`, this is what I get in picture below.

Is there a way to match the labels when trying to overlap histograms more using `g.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.9)` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the y-axis labels, the strings are created individually and the y-axis position is determined manually. So changing the y-axis coordinates in ax.text() will produce the intended result. I tried it manually and 0.045 seemed optimal. You can modify it to your liking.

```
# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .045, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]

Comment: How does the `label` function work? Is `label` a recursive function that calls itself on the `ax.text` line? And if so why?